# NG0204: Token InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is missing a ɵprov definition

Tags: angular, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I've crossed a problem with angular where I'm trying to implement the login module using JWT & spring security.
When the login button is clicked, a JWT token will be created and intercepted by HttpInterceptor.
but I'm getting this error and idk what it is.
(I'm using spring-boot as back-end)

This is the version I'm using -->

- Angular CLI: 15.0.1
- Node: 18.12.1
- Package Manager: npm 9.1.2

I'm not rly that into the front-end so I'm not rly good at that and am a beginner. I'm just trying to learn the back-end part so I'll be really grateful if someone could help me.

btw this is my code for HttpInterceptor.
I've created a class for serving the intercepting purpose:

```
         auth.interceptor.ts
```

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { LoginService } from "../login/login.service";

const TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let authReq = req;
        //get the token
        const token = this.loginService.getToken();
        //add the jwt token to the requests
        if (token != null) {
            authReq = authReq.clone({
                setHeaders: { TOKEN_HEADER: `Bearer ${token}` },
            });
        }
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    usecClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
}]
```

Comment: This might not be relevant but small typo: `usecClass` (extra c)

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled your export
"usecClass: AuthInterceptor," should be
"useClass: AuthInterceptor,"